# how to add dynamic textview and ontouchlistners android

Tags: android, textview

I have created 5 textview, now i want to know which textview has been touched. I have made a touchlistner but its referring only last one... plz guide me.

```
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);     


           for(int i=0; i< 5;i++){
             tv = new TextView(this);
             tv.setTextSize(90);
             tv.setId(i);
             tv.setText("Text");
             tvlist.add(tv);
             ll.addView(tv, i);
    } 




     tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("TAG", "touchdown" + Integer.toString(v.getId()));
            Log.i("TAG", "touchdown 2" + tvlist.get(v.getId()));

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Put the call to `tv.setOnTouchListener(...)` inside your `for` loop before `tvlist.add(tv);`

Answer (score 1):

Use like this and for better handling of textview you should go for TextView array

```
 for(int i=0; i< 5;i++){
         tv = new TextView(this);
         tv.setTextSize(90);
         tv.setId(i);
         tv.setText("Text");
         tvlist.add(tv);
         ll.addView(tv, i);


  tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("TAG", "touchdown" + Integer.toString(v.getId()));
        Log.i("TAG", "touchdown 2" + tvlist.get(v.getId()));

        return false;
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use as follows also:

```
TextView tv=new Textview[5];
int txtid =0;
for(int i=0; i< 5;i++){
     tv = new TextView(this);
     tv[i].setTextSize(90);
     tv[i].setId(i);
     tv[i].setText("Text");
     tv[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            txtid = tv[i].getId();
            return false;
     }
});
}


     ll.addView(tv);
```

Comment: TextView tv=new Textview[5]; is it possible to write like this?it will give compile time error.and if you have arrary tv then how you can add this directly like ll.addView(tv);If you do not know then why are you giving answer?If you know then give answer.Otherwise you can appreciate other by giving them vote.